# Mysql Query request overload server

Tags: mysql, search, select

I'm using "mysql select and" function to gather data from InnoDB database which is very large with more than 1 million of records. The site is a search engine, and the result pages looks like this.

```
http://example.com/search.php?term=google
```

Whenever a user visits a page like that a mysql select with term and is used so there's many queries every second. I have enabled cache queries for mysql and index but it still overloads.

Google Bot has been indexing my site in the past 4 hours and it's almost not possible to visit it.

I would appreciate if I could get any advice how to improve the search functionality, I'm new to large mysql databases so I don't know what to do.

Comment: So what you're saying is that you're being dos'd by Google Bot? I'm sorry, but that's just too funny. On a more helpful note, you should have search pages for your site closed to web crawlers. They should ideally only see content, not access search pages.

Comment: The thing is as I said my site is a search engine, and content is updated frequently so because of that the content page does send mysql query and gather the information to display.

Comment: Right, I understand. But if your site is a search engine, pages with search results should not be accessible by crawlers. Web crawlers should see information pertinent to your site, like maybe the home page, but not the result of your service (eg the search results). An example is that if a web crawler were to go to http://google.com it should be able to index the search page, but it should not be looking at possible searches from google.

Comment: @AlienHoboken You are right, but my site is music search engine and the pages being indexed helps to gather traffic from google. I was thinking of storing the results of mysql select in txt and load results from the txt file next time and update it like every week. What do you think?

Comment: From an SEO standpoint it still seems inadvisable to have all your searches indexed in that way, especially if they have outbound links which will hurt [PageRank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank). You don't need a bunch of pages indexed for google rank, that's not how PageRank works. Rather (iirc, I messed with it last semester) it's based on inbound/outbound links and the PageRanks of all related pages. For example, take Pandora. We all know of Pandora radio, but google it and only about one result shows up: http://www.google.com/search?q=pandora